# Would it be possible to update PHP version on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-7.1

Would it be possible to update  PHP version on Google App Engine? 
I would like to update to above PHP7.1
Is there  any solution for following problems ???

$ composer install

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.27) does not satisfy that requirement.

$ sudo apt install php7.1 php7.1-common php7.1-cli php7.１-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-common
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-common'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-common'
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php7.-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.-fpm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.-fpm'

Answer (score 1):

Googled a bit and saw the following question: 
[Upgrading PHP in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800221/upgrading-php-in-google-app-engine)

Seems like it is not possible, until you consider Mmanaged VMs (with a custom runtime).

Comment: this page shows installing Laravel 5.6
https://mikateach.com/setting-up-laravel-5-6-on-google-app-engine/